# html image is not displayed in ie 8

Tags: html

I have the following code

```
<img id="zoomImage" src="products/beddingSupplies/beddingSuppliesProtective/img/th_3.jpg" width="" height="" product="beddingSuppliesProtective3" category="beddingSuppliesProtective" />
<img id="zoomImage" src="products/beddingSupplies/beddingSuppliesProtective/img/th_4.jpg" width="" height="" product="beddingSuppliesProtective4" category="beddingSuppliesProtective" />
<img id="zoomImage" src="products/beddingSupplies/beddingSuppliesProtective/img/th_2.jpg" width="" height="" product="beddingSuppliesProtective2" category="beddingSuppliesProtective" />
```

The above is working perfectly in all browsers except of the last image and only in ie8. I tried to reorder the images but yet not displayed no matter if is in first raw second third or last. Can you please help me out. The image exists in the directory. I also remove the width and height attributes, rename the image, clear cache and still nothing.

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rtAwu/1/ it is working in IE too, Check the path of the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just open the image in photoshop and save it without any changes and now is displaying... I have no idea what was wrong!!!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: check my answer the problem was that image was saved as CMYK after changing into RGB it worked

Answer (score 1):

Although this [article](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/jpeg-problems-in-firefox-and-ie/) is rather old, it might be of use.

If the JPG image was saved using CMYK instead of RGB it may have trouble displaying. It looks like the older versions of IE (and Firefox) have a problem with this.

From what you have told us, the most likely problem is that the image is in CMYK format which is only supported on IE9+ (for the IE browsers).

Convert it to RGB and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the 3 reasons:

1. image extension may be .jpe or jpeg
2. all ids are same
3. no width and height defined.

Custom attributes supported by IE8 so it not seems markup specific issue.

Comment: I've change my code to the following
           <img src="products/beddingSupplies/beddingSuppliesProtective/img/th_2.jpg" width="80" height="60" product="beddingSuppliesProtective2" category="beddingSuppliesProtective" />

Still nothing

Comment: Check image extension, it may be .jpe or .jpeg.